# What does = { 0 }; mean in a structure initialization in C?

Tags: c, variables, variable-assignment

When setting a struct variable as follows:

```
WNDCLASSW wc = {0};
```

What does the initialization with `{0}` mean for this variable in C?

Comment: In C slang this is called an initializer, because it appears where the variable is defined. This `{  0 }` is only valid for such an initializer, later for normal assignment this would be invalid.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification Jens, makes total sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the initialization rules of C, it's kind of a universal initializer:
it will initialize numbers or pointers as well as aggregates (=`struct`s/`union`s) or arrays by setting everything (every member recursively) to zero.

For block scope objects on platforms where the null pointer is "all bits zero" (most platforms), it's equivalent to `memset(&object,0,sizeof(object));` and compilers will often generate such a `memset` call for `{0}` initializations, particularly when such initializations are applied to a larger object.

Comment: This is a great answer! Thank you so much PSkocik, that was very detailed and informative!

Answer (score 4):

It will initialize all members of the struct to zero.

In most cases/architectures, that will be the same as setting all its memory to zero.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer Acorn, that helped a ton!